# Apache 2.4 list prefork directive values from command line

Tags: apache-2.4, httpd, httpd.conf, mpm-prefork

I am unable to find values of MPM Prefork directives like **MaxRequestWorkers**/**MaxSpareThreads** etc in my config file. Is there a way to list these values from command line?

```
-bash-4.2# httpd -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.23 (Amazon)

-bash-4.2# httpd -V
Server version: Apache/2.4.23 (Amazon)
Server built:   Jul 29 2016 21:42:17
Server's Module Magic Number: 20120211:61
Server loaded:  APR 1.5.1, APR-UTIL 1.4.1
Compiled using: APR 1.5.1, APR-UTIL 1.4.1
Architecture:   64-bit
Server MPM:     prefork
  threaded:     no
    forked:     yes (variable process count)
Server compiled with....
 -D APR_HAS_SENDFILE
 -D APR_HAS_MMAP
 -D APR_HAVE_IPV6 (IPv4-mapped addresses enabled)
 -D APR_USE_SYSVSEM_SERIALIZE
 -D APR_USE_PTHREAD_SERIALIZE
 -D SINGLE_LISTEN_UNSERIALIZED_ACCEPT
 -D APR_HAS_OTHER_CHILD
 -D AP_HAVE_RELIABLE_PIPED_LOGS
 -D DYNAMIC_MODULE_LIMIT=256
 -D HTTPD_ROOT="/etc/httpd"
 -D SUEXEC_BIN="/usr/sbin/suexec"
 -D DEFAULT_PIDLOG="/var/run/httpd/httpd.pid"
 -D DEFAULT_SCOREBOARD="logs/apache_runtime_status"
 -D DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="logs/error_log"
 -D AP_TYPES_CONFIG_FILE="conf/mime.types"
 -D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="conf/httpd.conf"
```

PS: I have posted it on SuperUser as well. I am not sure which one is the right place.

Answer (score 1):

1. you will never find MaxSpareThreads because prefork is not threaded, so it should be `**MaxSpareServers**`
2. Not from the command line, you need to **"cat" your main configuration file**, or whereever your distro has placed them (httpd.conf or apache.conf or mpm.conf?)
3. If you have **mod_info** you can "**curl**" your server for its information and parse/read the settings from it, that's the closest thing to get that info from command line you will probably find. There you will see a section called **Module name: prefork.c** and after some text something that says "**Current Configuration:**" which shows your actual **mpm settings**. (note: mod_info should not be publicaly available in your server to anyone that accesses it since it practically reveals your whole configuration).

Should you need further info about how prefork is/should be configured you can check it at the [official docs about mpm prefork](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/prefork.html)

Note: I would not recommend prefork anways, go for event and if it is because mod_php, ditch it in favour of php-fpm.

Comment: Even MaxSpareServers is nowhere to be found. Checked everything in conf/  conf.d/  conf.modules.d/. conf.modules.d has a file named 00-mpm.conf. Only uncommented line there is this : LoadModule mpm_prefork_module modules/mod_mpm_prefork.so

Comment: no problem, add/set them yourself then, most directives have default values so if they are not specified you will get the default values, you can check them in the official docs I linked.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the other approaches suggested here, I find my Apache distribution has a directory `/usr/share/doc/httpd-2.4.54` which contains templates and files of various settings.  Among them, `httpd-default.conf` claims that it *reflects default settings for Apache HTTP Server*.

I have not proven it but suspect this is true of another file located here, `httpd-mpm.conf`.  This file contains sections of settings related to MPM with this preamble:

```
# Only one of the below sections will be relevant on your
# installed httpd.  Use "apachectl -l" to find out the
# active mpm.
```

Apparently `-l` above is a typo; in my case, I run `apachectl -V`, which tells me:

```
Architecture:   64-bit
Server MPM:     prefork
  threaded:     no
    forked:     yes (variable process count)
Server compiled with....
```

So I consult the section of `httpd-mpm.conf` pertaining to *prefork MPM*, which contains:

````
# prefork MPM
# StartServers: number of server processes to start
# MinSpareServers: minimum number of server processes which are kept spare
# MaxSpareServers: maximum number of server processes which are kept spare
# MaxRequestWorkers: maximum number of server processes allowed to start
# MaxConnectionsPerChild: maximum number of connections a server process serves
#                         before terminating
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
    StartServers             5
    MinSpareServers          5
    MaxSpareServers         10
    MaxRequestWorkers      250
    MaxConnectionsPerChild   0
</IfModule>```
````